# how to get best results in Doc2vec

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

1. As I came to know we need a large dataset to get results so I found a 50k plus abstracts dataset to check.
2. Now to test whether this is working correctly or not I wanted to match the target document into the trained document.

   ```
    doc = 'Noise pollution can cause health problems for people and wildlife both on land 
     and in the sea. From traffic noise to rock concerts loud or inescapable sounds can 
     cause hearing loss stress and high blood pressure Noise from ships and human activities 
     in the ocean is harmful to whales and dolphins that depend on echolocation to survive.'
    target_data = word_tokenize(lst_doc)

    train_data = list(read_data())
    model = gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec(vector_size=100, min_count=3, epochs=20)
    train_vocab = model.build_vocab(train_data)
    train = model.train(train_data, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.epochs)


    inferred_vector = model.infer_vector(target_data)
    sims = model.dv.most_similar([inferred_vector])
    print('Document ({}): «{}»\n'.format(0,' '.join(target_data)))
    print(u'SIMILAR/DISSIMILAR DOCS PER MODEL %s:\n' % model)
    for  index in sims:
        print(index, ' '.join(train_data[index[0]].words))
        print('\n')
   ```

**Current Output**

```
(56182, 0.8743067383766174) noise pollution can cause health problems for people and wildlife both on land and in the sea from traffic noise to rock concerts loud or inescapable sounds can cause hearing loss stress and high blood pressure noise from ships and human activities in the ocean is harmful to whales and dolphins that depend on echolocation to survive


(56183, 0.5959663391113281) global warming also known as climate change is caused by blanket of pollution that traps heat around the earth this pollution comes from cars factories homes and power plants that burn fossil fuels such as oil coal natural gas and gasoline


(21926, 0.5771061182022095) collecting sufficient labelled training data for health and medical problems is difficult antropova et al also missing values are unavoidable in health and medical datasets and tackling the problem arising from the inadequate instances and missingness is not straightforward snell et al sterne et al however machine learning algorithms have achieved significant success in many real world healthcare problems such as regression and classification and these techniques could possibly be way to resolve the issues


(12118, 0.5548962950706482) the policy gradients of the expected return objective can react slowly to rare rewards yet in some cases agents may wish to emphasize the low or high returns regardless of their probability borrowing from the economics and control literature we review the risk sensitive value function that arises from an exponential utility and illustrate its effects on an example this risk sensitive value function is not always applicable to reinforcement learning problems so we introduce the particle value function defined by particle filter over the distributions of an agent experience which bounds the risk sensitive one we illustrate the benefit of the policy gradients of this objective in cliffworld


(6635, 0.5334600806236267) crowd gatherings at social and cultural events are increasing in leaps and bounds with the increase in population surveillance through computer vision and expert decision making systems can help to understand the crowd phenomena at large gatherings understanding crowd phenomena can be helpful in early identification of unwanted incidents and their prevention motion flow is one of the important crowd phenomena that can be instrumental in describing the crowd behavior flows can be useful in understanding instabilities in the crowd however extracting motion flows is challenging task due to randomness in crowd movement and limitations of the sensing device moreover low level features such as optical flow can be misleading if the randomness is high in this paper we propose new model based on langevin equation to analyze the linear dominant flows in videos of densely crowded scenarios we assume force model with three components namely external force confinement drift force and disturbance force these forces are found to be sufficient to describe the linear or near linear motion in dense crowd videos the method is significantly faster as compared to existing popular crowd segmentation methods the evaluation of the proposed model has been carried out on publicly available datasets as well as using our dataset it has been observed that the proposed method is able to estimate and segment the linear flows in the dense crowd with better accuracy as compared to state of the art techniques with substantial decrease in the computational overhead


(30405, 0.5323445200920105) wildfires have increased in frequency and severity over the past two decades especially in the western united states beyond physical infrastructure damage caused by these wildfire events researchers have increasingly identified harmful impacts of particulate matter generated by wildfire smoke on respiratory cardiovascular and cognitive health this inference is difficult due to the spatial and temporal uncertainty regarding how much particulate matter is specifically attributable to wildfire smoke one factor contributing to this challenge is the reliance on manually drawn smoke plume annotations which are often noisy representations limited to the united states this work uses deep convolutional neural networks to segment smoke plumes from geostationary satellite imagery we compare the performance of predicted plume segmentations versus the noisy annotations using causal inference methods to estimate the amount of variation each explains in environmental protection agency epa measured surface level particulate matter um in diameter textrm pm


(5699, 0.5295888781547546) crowd gatherings at social and cultural events are increasing in leaps and bounds with the increase in population surveillance through computer vision and expert decision making systems can help to understand the crowd phenomena at large gatherings understanding crowd phenomena can be helpful in early identification of unwanted incidents and their prevention motion flow is one of the important crowd phenomena that can be instrumental in describing the crowd behavior flows can be useful in understanding instabilities in the crowd however extracting motion flows is challenging task due to randomness in crowd movement and limitations of the sensing device moreover low level features such as optical flow can be misleading if the randomness is high in this paper we propose new model based on langevin equation to analyze the linear dominant flows in videos of densely crowded scenarios we assume force model with three components namely external force confinement drift force and disturbance force these forces are found to be sufficient to describe the linear or near linear motion in dense crowd videos the method is significantly faster as compared to existing popular crowd segmentation methods the evaluation of the proposed model has been carried out on publicly available datasets as well as using our dataset it has been observed that the proposed method is able to estimate and segment the linear flows in the dense crowd with better accuracy as compared to state of the art techniques with substantial decrease in the computational overhead


(11825, 0.5268296003341675) recent advances in policy gradient methods and deep learning have demonstrated their applicability for complex reinforcement learning problems however the variance of the performance gradient estimates obtained from the simulation is often excessive leading to poor sample efficiency in this paper we apply the stochastic variance reduced gradient descent svrg to model free policy gradient to significantly improve the sample efficiency the svrg estimation is incorporated into trust region newton conjugate gradient framework for the policy optimization on several mujoco tasks our method achieves significantly better performance compared to the state of the art model free policy gradient methods in robotic continuous control such as trust region policy optimization trpo


(18521, 0.5255249738693237) cnns perform remarkably well when the training and test distributions are but unseen image corruptions can cause surprisingly large drop in performance in various real scenarios unexpected distortions such as random noise compression artefacts or weather distortions are common phenomena improving performance on corrupted images must not result in degraded performance challenge faced by many state of the art robust approaches image corruption types have different characteristics in the frequency spectrum and would benefit from targeted type of data augmentation which however is often unknown during training in this paper we introduce mixture of two expert models specializing in high and low frequency robustness respectively moreover we propose new regularization scheme that minimizes the total variation tv of convolution feature maps to increase high frequency robustness the approach improves on corrupted images without degrading in distribution performance we demonstrate this on imagenet and also for real world corruptions on an automotive dataset both for object classification and object detection


(20234, 0.5212455987930298) deep learning on an edge device requires energy efficient operation due to ever diminishing power budget intentional low quality data during the data acquisition for longer battery life and natural noise from the low cost sensor degrade the quality of target output which hinders adoption of deep learning on an edge device to overcome these problems we propose simple yet efficient mixture of pre processing experts mope model to handle various image distortions including low resolution and noisy images we also propose to use adversarially trained auto encoder as pre processing expert for the noisy images we evaluate our proposed method for various machine learning tasks including object detection on ms coco dataset multiple object tracking problem on mot challenge dataset and human activity classification on ucf dataset experimental results show that the proposed method achieves better detection tracking and activity classification accuracies under noise without sacrificing accuracies for the clean images the overheads of our proposed mope are and in terms of memory and computation compared to the baseline object detection network
```

Comment: In your output (which would be better to share as a quoted block of text in your question than a raw image), I see only 4 documents reported. Normally, a `.most_similar()` against a 50k document model would give at least 10 responses. Were there more and you're only showing 4? Also: the top hit seems very relevant; whethe others are best remaining depends on what's in the dataset. Why do you think these results are not good? Are there other docs in the training set that you think *should* be there? What's in those docs? How far down in the list-of-similars (if you increase `topn`) are they?

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I have updated the results in the textual form please have a look. Secondly, I run it again now it's showing first 2 most relevant but not every time. the dataset is based upon an abstract related to machine learning graph neural network which could be quite irrelevant to the target document. Although manually I added 3 articles first two in result but not this one**Noise pollution is generally defined as regular exposure to elevated sound levels that may lead to adverse effects in humans or other living organisms.** which is also expected but no shown.

Comment: Thanks for the updated output. There's now the 10 expected values, and the 1st hit still looks good. Are you sure the other articles were truly in the training set? Also, I see document IDs over 50,000 - how big exactly is your training-set? More generally: I would not expect taking one aribtrary set-of-docs (say, computer science research), then mixing in 3 documents from another domain, to work very well in testing/demonstrating `Doc2Vec`. Those 3 docs may use words very differently than the other 49,997!

Comment: These models learn from variety & word-usage patterns in their training data. If you want a model good at distinguishing 'pollution' docs from some broader set of documents, in a real deployment, you'll want to train your model on texts fully representative of docs it'll have to rank later: a wide variety of 'pollution' docs, mixed in with whatever sorts of documents they might be alongside in your real ultimate usage situation. Only then will it learn word-senses/topic-patterns that are relevant. So be careful about contrived/constructed tests. Choose realistic data/tests whenever possible.

Comment: Thanks for answering current dataset is  56000. can you suggest to me some online real datasets? Secondly, can you suggest another NLP  technique rather than doc2vec so I can check the competitive results? 
Can I use topic modeling or topic classification for above mentioned usecase

Comment: Different tutorials will often suggest certain datasets; a set of old forum posts called `20newsgroups` is one popular one, or often Wikipedia is used when people need lots of data (& have the time to process its many gigabytes!). But if you're developing to handle a real problem in your environment, using real data from that domain (or something very similar you may be able to find) is best, even if it takes some extra effort to collect/clean. Yes, other topic-modeling algorithms like LDA might be good as comparions.

Comment: Once again Thanks I got the clean dataset but that is only 1400 and I think that is not enough to perform results right? LDA can give some good results on less number of datasets?

Comment: 1400 is quite small; by lowering the `vector_size` & raising the `epochs`, you can still get some useful `Doc2Vec` results on smaller datasets (if they still have useful internal variety/patterns) - but you won't be seeing the full benefits of this style of algorithm on large/rich data. I've more often seen LDA demonstrated on smaller document sets, so you may be on safer ground there – again possibly lowering the number of topics & increasing the passes to help somewhat make-the-most from thin data. But always: more data, of representative quality, always helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I must appreciate your help is there possible to keep in touch with you related to this topic for further questions via email or another channel, or this is the only platform where you answer?

Comment: By asking at StackOverflow, many people can answer, and the answers can be easily found by others encountering similar problems – so here is best!